# Orthogonality of eigenfunctions corresponding to an eigenvalue having multiplicity

Tags: orthogonality, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

A Sturm-Liouville's problem is defined as follows:
$$(py')'-qy=-\lambda wy$$
where the functions $p(x)$ , $q(x)$ and $w(x)$ are known for $0<x<L$ and $y(x)$ and $\lambda$ are unknown.
It is shown that infinite number of eigenfunctions $y_k$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ exist and they have the orthogonality property:
$$ n\neq k : \int_0^L w y_k y_n dx = 0 $$
The above equality holds if the two eigenfunctions $y_k$ and $y_n$ correspond to two different eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ and $\lambda_n$. However, some eigenvalues may be multiple; e.g. more than one eigenfunction correspond to a specific eigenvalue. What about two different eigenfunctions that correspond to one eigenvalue that has multiplicity? Are they still orthogonal? Please provide proof.

Comment: What you say really isn't true in general without homogeneous endpoint conditions for the eigenfunctions. There are some cases where the equation is singular at both endpoints where conditions are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *necessarily* true that two independent eigenfunctions corresponding to a common eigenvalue are orthogonal.  However, if $\ y_1\ $ and $\ y_2\ $ are any two such independent eigenfunctions, then $\ \alpha y_1+\beta y_2\ $ is an eigenfunction, corresponding to the same eigenvalue, for *any* pair of scalars $\ \alpha\ $ and $\ \beta\ $.  So if $\ y_1\ $ and $\ y_2\ $ are *not* orthogonal, then you can choose
\begin{align}
\alpha&=-\frac{\int_0^Ly_1y_2dx}{\int_0^Ly_1^2\ dx}\ \ \text{and}\\
\beta&=1
\end{align}
to get
$$
\hat{y}_2=\alpha y_1+y_2\ ,
$$
which *is* orthogonal to $\ y_1\ $, still independent of it, and still an eigenfunction corresponding to the same eigenvalue.

More generally, if $\ y_1, y_2, \dots\ $ are linearly independent eigenfunctions, all corresponding to the same eigenvalue, but not necessarily mutually orthogonal, then you can apply the [Gram-Schmidt procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to them to get a set $\ y_1,\hat{y}_2,\hat{y}_3,\dots\ $ of linearly independent and mutually orthogonal eigenfunctions corresponding to the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Complete answer, thank you. I couldn't prove that why $\alpha y_1+y_2$ is orthogonal to $y_1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int_0^Ly_1\big(\alpha y_1+y_2\big)\,dx&=\alpha\int_0^Ly_1^2\,dx+\int_0^Ly_1y_2\,dx\\
&=0
\end{align}
if $\ \alpha=-\frac{\int_0^Ly_1y_2dx}{\int_0^Ly_1^2\ dx}\ $.